# unable to decode stream java.io.FileNotFoundException /storage/emulated/0 open failed:ENOENT(No such file or directory

Tags: android, eclipse, timer, android-camera, capture

hello i'm trying to save pictures taken on my application, but when i try to access the memory to place the data, an error comes out

unable to decode stream java.io.FileNotFoundException /storage/emulated/0 open failed:ENOENT(No such file or directory)

this is my code.

```
            Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (data != null){
                //Intent mIntent = new Intent();
                //mIntent.putExtra("image",imageData);

                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mPreviewRunning = false;
                mCamera.release();

                 try{
                     BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                     Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,opts);
                     bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, false);
                     int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                     int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                     int newWidth = 300;
                     int newHeight = 300;

                     // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
                     float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
                     float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

                     // createa matrix for the manipulation
                     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                     // resize the bit map
                     matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                     // rotate the Bitmap
                     matrix.postRotate(-90);
                     Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                             width, height, matrix, true);
                     Camera_local_db.image.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

                 }catch(Exception e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
               // StoreByteImage(mContext, imageData, 50,"ImageName");
                //setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
                setResult(585);
                finish();
            }       
        }
    };


    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new Camera. PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {


        File dir_image2 = new  File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"dddd.jpg");
        dir_image2.mkdirs();  //AGAIN CHOOSING FOLDER FOR THE PICTURE(WHICH IS LIKE A SURFACEVIEW 
                                //SCREENSHOT)
        if (!dir_image2.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Directory not created");
        }


        File tmpFile = new File(dir_image2,"TempGhost.jpg"); //MAKING A FILE IN THE PATH                 
                        //dir_image2(SEE RIGHT ABOVE) AND NAMING IT "TempGhost.jpg" OR ANYTHING ELSE
        try {//SAVING
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            //grabImage();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(    Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES); File file = new File(path, "/" + dir_image2);
        //String path = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)+  
          //      File.separator+"TempGhost.jpg");//<---

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();//<---
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//<---
        bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmpFile.toString(), options);//<---
        //THE LINES ABOVE READ THE FILE WE SAVED BEFORE AND CONVERT IT INTO A BitMap
        Camera_local_db.image.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
        //camera_image.setImageBitmap(bmp1); //SETTING THE BitMap AS IMAGE IN AN IMAGEVIEW(SOMETHING
                                    //LIKE A BACKGROUNG FOR THE LAYOUT)
       // TakeScreenshot();//CALLING THIS METHOD TO TAKE A SCREENSHOT

    }
    };
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to write to external storage, make sure you added the permission:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Checks if external storage is available for read and write:

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use the root of the public directory instead of using the root of Android.

If you want to save public files on the external storage, use the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()

```
public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory. 
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

If you want to save files that are private to your app, use the getExternalFilesDir()

```
public File getAlbumStorageDir(Context context, String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the app's private pictures directory. 
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

More information on the link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 4):

First, you are writing the image to a different location than you are reading it from. Rather than rebuild `path`, use the `tmpFile` value that you already have.

Second, do not use `getRootDirectory()` to get the `DCIM` directory. Use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`.

Third, use `Log` methods to log exceptions, rather than just display a `Toast`, as you may miss the `Toast` and you do not get the stack trace associated with your exception.

Comment: please see my answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59877434/3904109

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, and the only problem was the permission in android manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved using this:

```
private static final int WRITE_PERMISSION = 0x01;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    requestWritePermission();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == WRITE_PERMISSION){
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Write Permission Failed");
            Toast.makeText(this, "You must allow permission write external storage to your mobile device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

private void requestWritePermission(){
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},WRITE_PERMISSION);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If it fails with this permission is present already, then you need to check your app's target SDK level. If it is targetSdkVersion => 23, then you need to request permissions at Run Time.
[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check)